# What are Ably Presence action numbers?

Tags: real-time, ably-realtime

So I'm pushing Ably Presence events to a lambda function via Ably Firehouse. Logging the event on lambda, I see the presence actions are represented by numbers and not action names (leave, enter...) but I'm not sure what actions each number represents.

Below is the event log on lambda.

```
 body: '{"source":"channel.presence","appId":"appId","channel":"room:0685f760-f2c9-423b-b44c-19bbefc60358","site":"eu-central-1-A","ruleId":"TtncNQ","presence":[{"id":"WR4hNYLhh-:5:0","clientId":"42e00149-6fbc-4d19-8984-dce2b41d4474","connectionId":"WR4hNYLhh-","timestamp":1695474395301,"encoding":"json","data":"{\\"id\\":\\"42e00149-6fbc-4d19-8984-dce2b41d4474\\",\\"username\\":\\"jondoe\\",\\"firstName\\":\\"Joh\\",\\"lastName\\":\\"Nameless\\"}","action":3}]}',
```

Playing with my app and observing the logs, it appears that the number 2 represents "Enter" event while 3 represents "Leave". But I wish to have a concrete guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ably presence action are:

```js
0: ABSENT, 
1: PRESENT,
2: ENTER,
3: LEAVE,
4: UPDATE
```

In practice you should see only 2,3 and 4.

Source: [Ably documentation](https://ably.com/docs/api/realtime-sdk/types#presence-message)